# Съезжает картинка

Tags: html, css, img, position, display

У меня имеется div (stories), в котором находится много div'ов (story), в которых находится либо img картинка, либо video видео.

```
<div class="stories">

  <div class="story">
    <img src="ссылка0">
  </div>
 
  <div class="story">
    <video controls=""><source src="ссылка1" type="video/mp4">Ошибка</video>
  </div>

  <div class="story">
    <video controls=""><source src="ссылка2" type="video/mp4">Ошибка</video>
  </div>

  <div class="story">
    <video controls=""><source src="ссылка3" type="video/mp4">Ошибка</video>
  </div>

</div>
```

И имеется стиль к этому всему:

```
.stories {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 306px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.story {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 174px;
}

img, video {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

При попытке сделать окно, в котором можно пролистывать "влево-вправо" картинки и видео, возникает проблема: img съезжает на 50% вниз, причём все video располагаются как надо. img съезжает в любом случае, находясь до video, между video, и после video.

Вот, как это выглядит.

[image]

Хочется, чтобы и картинки, и видео находились на одном уровне. Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: разместите тот код, с которым у вас проблема, чтобы блоки так же неправильно были выставлены, тогда появится возможность вам помочь

Comment: @Arcadiy, прошу, вот код, разместил на Codepen: https://codepen.io/l-il/pen/KKXELao?editors=1100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант сделать все через `Flex`

```css
.stories {
overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 306px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.story {display: flex;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 100%;
    width: 174px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;}

img, video {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="stories">

  <div class="story">
    <img src="ссылка0">
  </div>
 
  <div class="story">
    <video controls=""><source src="ссылка1" type="video/mp4">Ошибка</video>
  </div>

  <div class="story">
    <video controls=""><source src="ссылка2" type="video/mp4">Ошибка</video>
  </div>

  <div class="story">
    <video controls=""><source src="ссылка3" type="video/mp4">Ошибка</video>
  </div>

</div>
```